# Telerik version of system.windows.text code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik

I want to have a partial class to manage my focus between `radtextboxes` when a user presses the enter key and I am looking for the telerik interpretation of this line of code `tbs(i).KeyDown += New KeyEventHandler(AddressOf textBoxes_KeyDown)` Any ideas. Please help.

```
Partial Public Class MstFileTruck Inherits Form

    Private tbs() As Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        tbs = New Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox() {txtTruckNumber,   txtRegistrationNumber, txtOwnerName}
        For i As Integer = 0 To tbs.Length - 1
            tbs(i).Tag = i
            tbs(i).KeyDown += New KeyEventHandler(AddressOf textBoxes_KeyDown)
            '    'tbs(i).IsHandleCreated += New KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter) '(AddressOf textBoxes_KeyDown)
            '    tbs(i).RootElement.KeyDownEvent.EventName(textBoxes_KeyDown) '= New KeyEventArgs(AddressOf   Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBoxElement.KeyDownEvent.EventName(textBoxes_KeyDown(tbs, RootRadElement.KeyDownEvent))) '(AddressOf textBoxes_KeyDown)
        Next
        tbs(0).Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub textBoxes_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        Dim tb As Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox = TryCast(sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox)
        If tb IsNot Nothing Then
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                Dim tag As Integer = CInt(tb.Tag)
                If tag = 2 Then
                    tbs(0).Focus()
                Else
                    tbs(tag + 1).Focus()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: From what i remember of using Telerik last year, normally you don't have to make to many adjustments to use their controls. I believe the reference you are looking for ist System.Windows.UIElements or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your code should do. I am not even sure that your event subscription will work, however, here is how to switch the focus between two instances of RadTextBox:

```
 Private Sub RadTextBox_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RadTextBox1.KeyDown, RadTextBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim tb As RadTextBox = DirectCast(sender, RadTextBox)
        If tb.Name = "RadTextBox1" Then
            RadTextBox2.TextBoxElement.Focus()
        Else
            RadTextBox1.TextBoxElement.Focus()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Another way to subscribe to an event in VB is:

```
        AddHandler RadTextBox1.KeyDown, AddressOf RadTextBox_KeyDown

        Private Sub RadTextBox_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
           'your code here
        End Sub
```

here is the whole code as it should look like in your .vb file

```
Imports Telerik.WinControls.UI

Public Class Form1

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    AddHandler RadTextBox1.KeyDown, AddressOf RadTextBox_KeyDown
End Sub


Private Sub RadTextBox_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RadTextBox1.KeyDown, RadTextBox2.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim tb As RadTextBox = DirectCast(sender, RadTextBox)
        If tb.Name = "RadTextBox1" Then
            RadTextBox2.TextBoxElement.Focus()
        Else
            RadTextBox1.TextBoxElement.Focus()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: any ideas where exactly I can place this code because when I placed this code just under the class for my form my form got an major error and it was saying too many partial classes Can I copy the code into the Form.Designer code? Where exactly cxdan I copy the code

Comment: Create a form and add two text boxes in it, namely RadTextBox1 and RadTextBox2. The open the Form1.vb and make it look like the last code snippet from my answer above.